# Nopcommerce pricing tier grouped product not showing links to simple products

Tags: nopcommerce

When showing grouped products in NopCommerce.  It doesn't show links to each grouped product.  The simple product configuration shows this but the tiered pricing does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I used javascript to get all the grouped products and added the html back in.

```
$('.variant-name').each(function () { 
     var str = $(this).html().trim();
     str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
     $(this).attr('id', str);
     $('.product-name').append('<div><a href="#'+str+'">' + $(this).html().trim() + '</a></div>');
});
```